# How can the body statement and iteration expression of a for statement be in disjoint scopes?

Tags: c++, for-loop, scope, language-lawyer

According to the C++ standard (cf. [§ [stmt.for]](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.for)):

> The `for` statement
>
> ```cpp
> for (init-statement condition; expression) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```cpp
> {
>     init-statement
>     while (condition) {
>         statement
>         expression;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> except that the *init-statement* is in the same scope as the *condition*, and except that a `continue` in *statement* (not enclosed in another iteration statement) will execute *expression* before re-evaluating *condition*.

I noticed that the *statement* and *expression* are **not** in the same scope:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (; ; std::cout << i) {
        int i = 0;
        std::cout << i;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Clang output:

```
main.cpp:4:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for (; ; std::cout << i) {
                          ^
1 error generated.
```

Yet the *init-statement* and *statement* are in the same scope:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; ;) {
        std::cout << i;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Clang output:

```
0
```

And the *init-statement* and *expression* are in the same scope:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; ; std::cout << i) {
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Clang output:

How is that possible that the *init-statement* and *statement* are in the same scope, the *init-statement* and *expression* also are, but the *statement* and *expression* are not?

Comment: The `while` loop shown is *equivalent*, not *equal*.

Comment: The "in scope" relation is asymmetrical. In the simplest case, `int a = b; int b = a;` the second initializer is ok, while the first one isn't.

Comment: I can't write `int x = y; int y = 10;`, even though `x` and `y` are in the same scope. The order of your lines of code matters.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes but here the sequence is `init-statement; condition; statement; expression;`, so if `init-statement` and `condition` are in the same scope, `init-statement` and `statement` are in the same scope, and `init-statement` and `expression` are in the same scope, I expect `statement` and `expression` to also be in the same scope as well.

Comment: @Maggyero Yes, you already said this in the question. Did you understand my comment? *"A and B are in the same scope"* isn't a thing. Rather, *"A is in the scope of B"* is a thing, and it's different from *"B is in the scope of A"*.

Comment: Compare this with `int a; if (...) {int b = a;} else {int c = a;}`. `b` is in the scope of `a`, and `c` is in the scope of `a`, but `b` and `c` aren't in the scope of each other.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for this important precision. I get your point. The problem is that in your example `b` and `c` are not really in the scope of `a`, they are in a *nested* scope of `a`. If they were in the scope of `a` you couldn’t redeclare `a` at their points.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat _"A and B are in the same scope" isn't a thing_ It is.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Just disagreeing isn't constructive. Can you elaborate or suggest better wording?

Comment: @Maggyero Ok, but my point still stands. Even if you do `int a; int b; int c;`, and say that both `b` and `c` are in the scope of `a`, that doesn't mean both of them can see each other.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed, but `c` can see `a` and `b`, whereas in the case of the `for` statement this is not the case (`expression` cannot see `statement` in `init-statement; condition; statement; expression;`), so your point doesn’t stand anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that the *statement* and *expression* are not in the same scope:

Yes, *statement*'s immediate scope and *expression*'s immediate scope are **disjoint**. The whole block after `for (…)`, including the braces, which introduce a new scope, are part of the *statement*.

So

```
for (; ; std::cout << i) {
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << i;
    break;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (; ;) {
    {
        int i = 0;
        std::cout << i;
        break;
    }
    std::cout << i;
}
```

with the exceptions from the standard quote. In particular `i`'s scope is the one with the inner braces. `i`'s scope ends before the `std::cout << i;` and so `i` isn't reachable there.

Furthermore https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-2 together with https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#block-1.2 specify that *statement* introduces itself a block scope, independent of whether it contains braces for *compound-statement*. So anything declared in *statement* never lives beyond it, even if *statement* is just a single declaration statement followed by the *expression* immediately.

---

> Yet the *init-statement* and *statement* are in the same scope:

No, *statement*'s immediate scope is **nested** within *init-statement*'s immediate scope. That's enough for a declaration inhabiting *init-statement*'s immediate scope to be visible in *statement*'s immediate scope.  https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#scope.block-2.2 specifies that the fact that `for (int i = 0; ;) { int i = 0; break; }` generates a redeclaration of `i` error is just a special case of nested scopes so it should not be interpreted as *init-statement* and *statement* sharing the same immediate scope.

> And the init-statement and expression are in the same scope:

No, *expression*'s immediate scope is **nested** within *init-statement*'s immediate scope. This is for the same reason.

---

All in all, *statement*'s immediate scope and *expression*'s immediate scope are **disjoint** and **nested** within *init-statement* and *condition*'s immediate scope:

```
  init-statement and condition's immediate scope
> statement's immediate scope
> expression's immediate scope
```

That’s how declarations in *statement*'s immediate scope are not visible in *expression*'s immediate scope while declarations in *init-statement* and *condition*'s immediate scope are visible in *statement*'s immediate scope and *expression*'s immediate scope.

Comment: ‘The immediate scope of *statement* is nested in that of *init-statement*.’ If the scope of *statement* was nested in that of *init-statement* then a redeclaration would be possible. Yet it generates an error so they *do* share the same scope. Try `for (int i = 0; ;) { int i = 0; break; }`

Comment: @Maggyero No, that's just because there is a specific rule prohibiting this specific case: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#scope.block-2.2

Comment: Oh! Do you mean that the scope of the *statement* is nested in that of the *init-statement* and the redeclaration error that we observe with the code in my previous comment is just a special case and in the other nested scope cases that are not listed in [\[basic.scope.block-2.2\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.block#2.2) a redeclaration would not cause any error, so we should not interpret that error as the *statement* and *init-statement* being in the same scope?

Comment: @Maggyero Yes, it is a special case. But the point is specifically that a second `int i = 0;` declaration with different immediate scope would _not_ be a redeclaration. They would be declarations for _different_ entities with the same name, the latter shadowing the former. For cases listed in 2.2, such declarations inhabiting different scopes and _not_ declaring the same entity, while still corresponding (i.e. sharing names), were forbidden. Yes, they are not the same scope. The normal expectation of how declarations in nested scopes behave just doesn't apply in this special case.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you nailed it with your reference to the C++ standard explaining why the scopes of the *statement* and *expression* are not the same but both are **nested** in the scope of the *init-statement* and *condition*, though they appear not to be nested but the same, solving the apparent contradiction mentioned in my original post. So could you add it to your answer to clarify for future readers? I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Compound statements (i.e. blocks enclosed by curly braces) always open a new scope. The curly braces on the `while` in the translated code *are not* the equivalent of the curly braces in your `for` body.

Your error case:

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    for (; ; std::cout << i) {
        int i = 0;
        std::cout << i;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

is roughly equivalent to the following `while`:

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    while (/* insert dummy condition here */) {
        {
            int i = 0;
            std::cout << i;
            break;
            //if you wanted to continue instead, uncomment this:
            // goto continue_label;
        }
      continue_label:
        std::cout << i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks ok apart from the `goto`. Why have that there?

Comment: oops - I was thinking of this snippet about `continue`:

> and except that a continue in statement (not enclosed in another iteration statement) will execute

and just transposed the semantics. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (; ; std::cout << i) {
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << i;
    break;
}
```

You interpret it a bit wrongly. When you extend *expression* with *statement*, the original expression is not that expression anymore, it's enclosed into braces, but you move it w/o braces. To keep it to be the original, it should be enclosed into braces. The equivalent code with valid scopes is

```
while (true) {
  {
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << i;
    break;
  }
  std::cout << i;  // i is not declared in this scope. 
}
```

Comment: Initially that’s also what I thought, but then how do you explain that *init-statement* is in the same scope as *statement* and *expression*?

Comment: @Maggyero The `init-statement` is _above_ the `while` loop so everything declared there is in scope. Like in the equivalent `while` loop you put in the question

Comment: @Maggyero I don't see a problem there, *expression* is in an inner scope of *init-statement* scope.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No the *init-statement* is not in a parent scope of *statement*, it is in the **same** scope. For instance if you redeclare a variable in *statement* you get an error.

Comment: If the *expression* was in an inner scope of the *init-statement* it would also be in an inner scope of the *statement* since the *init-statement* and *statement* are in the same scope. Yet we have an undeclared identifier error.

Comment: @Maggyero look at the equivalent while loop in your question. Declarations made in the init-statement is clearly in scope in the expression.